# Use fill/stroke with rounded rectangle that only has 3 sides in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I can create a rounded rectangle and use the fx (fill/stroke) but I only want a shape with three sides. Because it's not enclosed the fill/stroke etc won't work. I can create all four sides and add another layer to mask the side I don't want but wonder if there's a better way to do this in Photoshop

Comment: Just add a mask to the layer and mask out the side you don't want.

Comment: I did that but the stroke went around the layer mask. Is there a way to get it to not do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a mask to the layer. Then right-click (Windows) or Control-Click (Mac) and choose <kbd>Blending Options</kbd>.

Then tick the Box for <kbd>Layer Mask Hides Effects</kbd>.

[image: blending options]